# Add a timestamp column to view in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to add a timestamp column (called Ingestion_time) in view with NULL as default values. Here is my query for it;

```
      CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DATA_LAKE.DATA_ANALYTICS.RISK_PREDICT_DR_LATEST COPY GRANTS AS(

SELECT ACT_ID,
     PROBABILITY_FRAUD,
     PREDICTON_TIME AS PREDICTION_TIME,
     FRAUD_EXPLANATION,
     SAFE_EXPLANATION,
     RISK_FLAG,
     NULL AS Ingestion_Time TIMESTAMP_TZ
     
      
FROM DATA_LAKE.DATA_ANALYTICS.RISK_PREDICT_DR_AUD tab1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tab1.ACT_ID ORDER BY PREDICTON_TIME DESC)=1
);
```

But it is giving following error, `SQL compilation error: syntax error line 9 at position 32 unexpected 'TIMESTAMP_TZ'. syntax error line 13 at position 81 unexpected ')'.`. Kindly advise on how we can rectify this error regarding TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Data typing applies to tables, not VIEWS

Comment: You could cast the NULL to a TIMESTAMP, but what are you trying to achieve here?  You now have a column that will always be NULL in your view.  Did you want to coalesce that with an actual field from the underlying table?

Comment: @MikeWalton  Thanks for the rely. may I know the syntax to convert NULL to timestamp here. we just want to eave it as NULL but of timestamp type. Can you kindly help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DATA_LAKE.DATA_ANALYTICS.RISK_PREDICT_DR_LATEST COPY GRANTS AS(

SELECT ACT_ID,
     PROBABILITY_FRAUD,
     PREDICTON_TIME AS PREDICTION_TIME,
     FRAUD_EXPLANATION,
     SAFE_EXPLANATION,
     RISK_FLAG,
     NULL::timestamp_tz AS Ingestion_Time
     
      
FROM DATA_LAKE.DATA_ANALYTICS.RISK_PREDICT_DR_AUD tab1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tab1.ACT_ID ORDER BY PREDICTON_TIME DESC)=1
);
```